# Getting error while installing Apache Spark in mac

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables

I was trying to install Apache Spark and I was getting the following error [error when I run the spark-shell command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN6Mp.png)

[This is my Java Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUrJF.png)

[This is apache spark path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giebK.png)

This is my apache spark folder path "/Users/ishandusane/Desktop/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

Can anyone tell whats wrong

Comment: Fix your export to ```$JAVA_HOME/bin```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Ankit, seems you've missed a "$" sign in while setting the Java path.

Comment: Thank you pugmarx. I have corrected that mistake but it still giving me the same error as follows                                                                
 /Users/ishandusane/Desktop/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 71: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk1.8.0_252.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
/Users/ishandusane/Desktop/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
head: illegal line count -- -1

Comment: It's still not working.

Comment: Is your JAVA_HOME set correctly? what does 'ls -lar /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk1.8.0_252.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java' return?

Comment: No, it was not set correctly. I set it to something like this                                        `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home                                                       export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin and finally it was working`. Thanks for your help.